# Css3 transform touch input

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a transform 3D on a map object, however, when I transform the whole map the touch input doesn't follow and it results in panning not functioning when rotating the map full 180 the controls are inverted.

Is there a way to tell CSS to invert or rotate the way touch inputs are read by the browser to allow for a normal panning even when the map is rotated.

- I do know this isn't the preferred way of rotating a map, the library should have a function for it but in this case, it doesn't and the only solution is to rotate the whole div containing the map.

What I am wondering about is a way to do this either with CSS or to override angular in some way to modify the touch on a 360-degree variable.

The map changes rotation frequently, so it can't be a static solution.

Css used to rotate the map:

```
transform-origin: 50% 50%; transform: rotate({{deg}}deg); transition: 300ms ease-out;
```

Code behind that is:

```
$scope.degraw = Math.round(heading.magneticHeading);

var aR;
$scope.rot = $scope.rot || 0; // if rot undefined or 0, make 0, else rot
aR = $scope.rot % 360;
if ( aR < 0 ) { aR += 360; }
if ( aR < 180 && ($scope.degraw > (aR + 180)) ) { $scope.rot -= 360; }
if ( aR >= 180 && ($scope.degraw <= (aR - 180)) ) { $scope.rot += 360; }
 $scope.rot += ($scope.degraw - aR);

 if($scope.isInCompass == 1) {
   $scope.deg = $scope.rot * -1;
   $scope.northdeg = $scope.rot * -1;
 }
```

The panning and all movement is controlled by the map library, however the code I've been able to get out of the library (Might not be the code at all but atleast this is what I'm looking at right now)

```
_touchMove: function(a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        this._updateTouch(a);
        var b = this._touches,
            c, d = a.changedTouches.length,
            f, e, g, h;
        if (!(l("android") && l("safari") && 1 === a.targetTouches.length && a.touches.length === a.targetTouches.length && a.targetTouches.length === a.changedTouches.length && 0 === a.changedTouches[0].identifier && b[a.changedTouches[0].identifier] && 1 < this._touchIds.length)) {
            for (c = 0; c < d; c++)
                if (f = a.changedTouches[c], e = b[f.identifier]) g = Math.abs(f.pageX -
                    e.startX), f = Math.abs(f.pageY - e.startY), !e.moved && (g >= this.tapRadius || f >= this.tapRadius) && (e.moved = e.absMoved = !0), h = h ? h : e.moved;
            1 === this._numTouches ? (b = a.changedTouches[0], this._swipeActive ? this._fire("onSwipeMove", this._processTouchEvent(a, b)) : h && (this._swipeActive = !0, this._fire("onSwipeStart", this._processTouchEvent(a, b)))) : 2 === this._numTouches && (c = this._nodeTouches[0], d = this._nodeTouches[1], this._pinchActive ? this._fire("onPinchMove", this._processTouchEvent(a, [c, d])) : h && (h = b[c.identifier], e = b[d.identifier],
                b = Math.abs(h.startX - e.startX), h = Math.abs(h.startY - e.startY), e = Math.abs(c.pageX - d.pageX), g = Math.abs(c.pageY - d.pageY), Math.abs(Math.sqrt(e * e + g * g) - Math.sqrt(b * b + h * h)) >= 2 * this.tapRadius && (this._pinchActive = !0, this._fire("onPinchStart", this._processTouchEvent(a, [c, d])))))
        }
    },
```

Comment: A small piece of code is always better than the description of a piece of code.

Comment: Can you please specify how you handle the panning event?

Comment: I left you an incomplete answer that i hope can drive you somewhere. do you have a link to the library?

Comment: Its Arcgisjs 3.21 https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really understand that touch code, but the point is that you should transform the input to follow your rotation:

get a rotation matrix:

```
var radians = deg / 180 * Math.Pi;
var cos = Math.cos(radians), sin = Math.sin(radians);
var matrix = [cos, sin, -sin, cos];
```

get a rotated touch point:

```
   var rotatedX = matrix[0] * p.x + matrix[2] * p.y;
   var rotatedY = matrix[1] * p.x + matrix[3] * p.y;
```

At this point if you do not have a knowledge of how your input are handled you can do this:

```
var originalTouchMove = _touchMove;
_touchMove = function(a) {
  // inspect a and find where clientX and clientY are.
  // obtain rotatedX and rotatedY and overwrite them
  originalTouchMove(a) // a has been mutated with rotated coords
}
```